# Can I get some help regarding the Transpose function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

The tensor flow function "transpose" takes in a second argument called perm.
Could someone explain this to me with some examples perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to demonstrate on a larger matrix. So consider a (4,2,3) matrix

```
xx = tf.constant([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                  [ 4,  5,  6]],
                 [[ 7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12]],
                  [[ 13,  14,  15],
                  [16, 17, 18]],
                  [[ 19,  20,  21],
                  [22, 23, 24]]])

print('Shape of matrix:',xx.shape)
tf.transpose(xx)

>>> (4, 2, 3)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2, 4), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[ 1,  7, 13, 19],
        [ 4, 10, 16, 22]],

       [[ 2,  8, 14, 20],
        [ 5, 11, 17, 23]],

       [[ 3,  9, 15, 21],
        [ 6, 12, 18, 24]]], dtype=int32)>
```

If you noticed above, (4,2,3) matrix becomes (3,2,4). By default, tensorflow reverses the shape of the matrix.

So `tf.transpose(xx,perm=[2,1,0])` would have the same effect as `tf.transpose(xx)`

For example, `tf.transpose(xx,perm=[1,2,0])` would change the shape to (2,3,4).

If you're having trouble visualising what the transformation would look like, you need to get some practice on it.

To take an instance,

```
tf.transpose(xx,perm=[1,2,0])

>>>tf.Tensor(
[[[ 1  7 13 19]
  [ 2  8 14 20]
  [ 3  9 15 21]]

 [[ 4 10 16 22]
  [ 5 11 17 23]
  [ 6 12 18 24]]], shape=(2, 3, 4), dtype=int32)
```

notice that 4 goes to the last place, so we now need 4 elements in the inner array. So 0th element of the 4 arrays in the original `xx` (1,7,13,19) go in here for the first row.

And since 3 goes in the 2nd place, the inner matrix will have 3 rows, starting from the 0th element of the first array.